# Reverse direction of Animation from clockwise to counter clockwise

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an animation that is basically a circular path. This is the code`

```
let curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable()        
        var rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,220,220)

        rectangle.origin.x = self.view.center.x - 110
        rectangle.origin.y = self.view.center.y - 110


        CGPathAddEllipseInRect(curvedPath, nil, rectangle)
        pathAnimation.path = curvedPath
        pathAnimation.duration = 5.0

        pathAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

        pathAnimation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
        obstacle.layer.addAnimation(pathAnimation, forKey: nil)`
```

I'm using CGPaths! Any idea on how to make this? Just reverse the direction!

Comment: Is your obstacle object placed in any view?

Comment: Yes! It's a UIImageView placed on the view already, I have an outlet for it!

Comment: Apply CATransform3DMakeScale on the view instead of obstacle and it will work!

Comment: It works, thank you! Is there anyway to make these changes just to the obstacle? Because I think it will affect how my other objects will act

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us what kind of animation pathAnimation is, or so the setup, so it's pretty hard to know how to reverse your animation.

A trivial way to do this would be to flip the layer to be a mirror-image. You could apply a scale transform and reverse the sign on X or Y. Then your rotation should appear to go in the other direction.

```
obstacle.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(-1,1,1);
```

Comment: Oh sorry!   This is pathanimation      let pathAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation.init(keyPath: "position")

Comment: That doesn't seem to work though... Where do I put it?